# How to use Async.await() in Vert.x JUnit without hitting "VertxException: Thread blocked"?

Tags: vert.x

What am I doing wrong in this kind of Vert.x (generated) service proxy test:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class MinecraftTest {

    @Rule public RunTestOnContext contextRule = new RunTestOnContext();
    @Rule public Timeout timeoutRule = Timeout.seconds(7);

    @Test
    public void testWhenCommand(TestContext testContext) {
        TestMinecraft testMinecraftServer = new TestMinecraft();
        new ServiceBinder(contextRule.vertx()).setAddress(Minecraft.ADDRESS).register(Minecraft.class, testMinecraftServer);

        Minecraft minecraftAPI = Minecraft.createProxy(contextRule.vertx());

        Async commandRegistrationAsync = testContext.async();
        minecraftAPI.newCommand("", "test", event -> {
            System.out.println("whenCommand callback");
            commandRegistrationAsync.complete();
            System.out.println("whenCommand callback complete");
        });
        commandRegistrationAsync.awaitSuccess();

        testMinecraftServer.invokeCommand("test");
    }
}
```

Where `Minecraft` is a `@VertxGen @ProxyGen`.  It fails like this:

```
Jun 05, 2018 8:07:04 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 2802 ms, time limit is 2000
(...)
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
(...)
    at io.vertx.ext.unit.impl.CompletionImpl.awaitSuccess(CompletionImpl.java:80)
    at ch.vorburger.minecraft.storeys.api.test.MinecraftTest.testWhenCommand(MinecraftTest.java:56)
```

The full example is available to try out locally here:

```
git clone https://github.com/vorburger/minecraft-storeys-maker.git
cd minecraft-storeys-maker/api
git checkout 48a44c512fe4d8001906e79de4b773fd66346584
../gradlew test
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception does not mean that the test failed. This is the way that vertx notifies you that somethings is wrong because the thread is blocked (as in is processing some request) for too long. The correct asynchronous, non-blocking way to do that test would be like this:

```
public void testWhenCommand(TestContext testContext) {
    TestMinecraft testMinecraftServer = new TestMinecraft();
    new ServiceBinder(contextRule.vertx()).setAddress(Minecraft.ADDRESS).register(Minecraft.class, testMinecraftServer);

    Minecraft minecraftAPI = Minecraft.createProxy(contextRule.vertx());

    Async commandRegistrationAsync = testContext.async();
    minecraftAPI.newCommand("", "test", event -> {
        System.out.println("whenCommand callback");
        testMinecraftServer.invokeCommand("test");
        commandRegistrationAsync.complete();
        System.out.println("whenCommand callback complete");
    });
}
```

This way, the

```
testMinecraftServer.invokeCommand("test");
```

is called when the asynchronous call has been finished but the thread it self does not hang waiting for the result.

For calling a blocking IO you should use

```
executeBlocking
```

method.